# jQuery tabs ui not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

i tried using jquery ui for tabs on my webpage but there is some error and i cant debug it.

i looked at some of the other solutions posted and tried it all... still its not works.. please help with appropriate solution.

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> -->
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#tabs").tabs();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--TOP NAV-->
<div id="topNav">
  <div class="topNavWrap">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul id="mainNav">
        <li><a href="#">Season '13 / '14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">International Prize for "The Naked Theatre"</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Average</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="CL"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CL"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<!--BANNER NAV-->
<div id="bannerNav">
  <div class="bannerNavWrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="slides"> <img src="images/img-01.jpg" /> <img src="images/img-02.jpg" /> <img src="images/img-03.jpg" /> <img src="images/img-04.jpg" /> <a class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation" href="#"></a> <a class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation" href="#"></a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--CONTENT NAV-->
<div id="contentNav">
  <div class="contentNavWrap"> 
    <!--CONTENT LEFT NAV-->
    <div class="contentLeft">
      <h2 class="withBG">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <h3 class='wdm'>13/9 - 29/9</h3>
      <h2 class="heading">DESCRIPTION</h2>
      <p>Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città, dai più presti Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città, dai più presti Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città, dai più presti Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città. </p>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span class='icon-mail'></span>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span class='icon-users'></span>About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="">

    <p>Name
        <span class="your-name"><input type="text" aria-required="true" class="wdm_input" size="60" value="" name="your-name" /></span> </p>

    <p>Email
        <span class="your-email"><input type="email" aria-required="true" class="wdm_input" size="60" value="" name="your-email" /></span> </p>

    <p>Subject
        <span class="your-subject"><input type="text" class="wdm_input" size="60" value="" name="your-subject" /></span> </p>

    <p><input type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" value="Send" /></p>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus.</p>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    <!--CONTENT RIGHT NAV-->
    <div class="contentRight">
      <h2 class="heading">SPECIAL FEATURES</h2>
      <div class="contxt">
        <div class="bx">
          <div class="icon video"></div>
          <p class="FL noMargin">GUARDA IL VIDEO PROMO: <br />
            http://teatronohma/it/00007/4234/page.html</p>
          <div class="CL"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bx padB20">
          <div class="icon page"></div>
          <p class="FL noMargin">LEGGI LA RECENSIONE DELLO SPETTACOLO: <br />
            http://teatronohma.tv/it/00007/4234/page.html</p>
          <div class="CL"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bx"> <a href="#"><img src="images/btn.png"  /></a> </div>
        <h2 class="heading">CREDITS</h2>
        <p class="padB20">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </p>
        <h2 class="heading">INFO E PRENOTAZIONI</h2>
        <p>Per informazioni su biglietti e abbonamenti per i gruppi organiz zati, pomeridiane per le scuole, spettacoli educational, rivolgersi al Servizio Promozione Pubblico e Proposte Culturali. <br />
          tel. 02 72.333.216 <br />
          e-mail: promozione.pubblico@piccoloteatromilano.it</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CL"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--FOOTER NAV-->
<div id="footerNav">
  <div class="footerNavWrap">
    <div class="footerNavi">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lavora con noi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Archivio</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Note legali</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mappa del sito</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="CL"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#slides').slidesjs({
     width: 1024,
     height: 369,
     navigation: true
   });
});
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Move your code to a dom ready handler

Comment: I recommend to you refactor the code before you post question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> -->
        <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--TOP NAV-->
        <div id="topNav">
            <div class="topNavWrap">
                <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul id="mainNav">
                        <li><a href="#">Season '13 / '14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">International Prize for "The Naked Theatre"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Average</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="CL"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="CL"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--BANNER NAV-->
        <div id="bannerNav">
            <div class="bannerNavWrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="slides"> <img src="images/img-01.jpg" /> <img src="images/img-02.jpg" /> <img src="images/img-03.jpg" /> <img src="images/img-04.jpg" /> <a class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation" href="#"></a> <a class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation" href="#"></a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--CONTENT NAV-->
        <div id="contentNav">
            <div class="contentNavWrap">
                <!--CONTENT LEFT NAV-->
                <div class="contentLeft">
                    <h2 class="withBG">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
                    <h3 class='wdm'>13/9 - 29/9</h3>
                    <h2 class="heading">DESCRIPTION</h2>
                    <p>Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città, dai più presti Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città, dai più presti Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città, dai più presti Negli anni precedenti NO’HMA ha svolto la sua densa, dina mica attività in luoghi vari e diversi della città. </p>

                    <div id="tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span class='icon-mail'></span>Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span class='icon-users'></span>About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="tabs-1">
                            <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="">

                                <p>Name
                                    <span class="your-name"><input type="text" aria-required="true" class="wdm_input" size="60" value="" name="your-name" /></span> </p>

                                <p>Email
                                    <span class="your-email"><input type="email" aria-required="true" class="wdm_input" size="60" value="" name="your-email" /></span> </p>

                                <p>Subject
                                    <span class="your-subject"><input type="text" class="wdm_input" size="60" value="" name="your-subject" /></span> </p>

                                <p><input type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" value="Send" /></p>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs-2">
                            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--CONTENT RIGHT NAV-->
                <div class="contentRight">
                    <h2 class="heading">SPECIAL FEATURES</h2>
                    <div class="contxt">
                        <div class="bx">
                            <div class="icon video"></div>
                            <p class="FL noMargin">GUARDA IL VIDEO PROMO: <br />
                                http://teatronohma/it/00007/4234/page.html</p>
                            <div class="CL"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bx padB20">
                            <div class="icon page"></div>
                            <p class="FL noMargin">LEGGI LA RECENSIONE DELLO SPETTACOLO: <br />
                                http://teatronohma.tv/it/00007/4234/page.html</p>
                            <div class="CL"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bx"> <a href="#"><img src="images/btn.png"  /></a> </div>
                        <h2 class="heading">CREDITS</h2>
                        <p class="padB20">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </p>
                        <h2 class="heading">INFO E PRENOTAZIONI</h2>
                        <p>Per informazioni su biglietti e abbonamenti per i gruppi organiz zati, pomeridiane per le scuole, spettacoli educational, rivolgersi al Servizio Promozione Pubblico e Proposte Culturali. <br />
                            tel. 02 72.333.216 <br />
                            e-mail: promozione.pubblico@piccoloteatromilano.it</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="CL"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--FOOTER NAV-->
        <div id="footerNav">
            <div class="footerNavWrap">
                <div class="footerNavi">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Lavora con noi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Archivio</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Note legali</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mappa del sito</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="CL"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $('#slides').slidesjs({
                width: 1024,
                height: 369,
                navigation: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have included jquery two times: once in head and twice before the html tag close.

Comment: post a style file too, I can not see the page correctly without it